# How apply a function in data frame with if/ lessthan statement in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a data frame looks like the following:

```
df<- data.frame(
  X1 = seq(from = 7, to = 25, by = 2),
  X2 = c(7,  10 ,11, 12, 16, 17, 20, 24, 2, 30),
  X3 = 2:11
)
```

I want to substitute column X3 with the following logic

> if X1 lees than x2 then X3=0

Comment: `df$X3 = ifelse(df$X1 < df$X2, 0, df$X3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(X3 = ifelse(X1 < X2, 0, X3))
```

Output:

```
   X1 X2 X3
1   7  7  2
2   9 10  0
3  11 11  4
4  13 12  5
5  15 16  0
6  17 17  7
7  19 20  0
8  21 24  0
9  23  2 10
10 25 30  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response-

Answer (score 0):

You can do -

```
df$X3[df$X1 < df$X2] <- 0
df

#   X1 X2 X3
#1   7  7  2
#2   9 10  0
#3  11 11  4
#4  13 12  5
#5  15 16  0
#6  17 17  7
#7  19 20  0
#8  21 24  0
#9  23  2 10
#10 25 30  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% mutate(X3 = ifelse(X1 < X2,0,X3))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
df$X3 <- with(df, X3 * (X1 >= X2))
```